# Android,Coding an app and want to know how to indicate the to be install in SD card

Tags: android

I am building an heavy app (20mb) so i would like to know how to make as default installation  to install in SD card i try few tutorial but not success the version of my android code is 2.2.

I add in the manifest the line:

```
 android:installLocation="preferExternal"
```

but nothing happen

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
<supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"/>
    <activity android:name=".Toto"
              android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I will appreciate Help!!!

Comment: Can you post your manifest? Also, what phone are you using? I don't think all of them support SD card installation.

Answer (score 0):

You should read carefully [this description](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html) on Android Developers, and make sure, that

- your SD card is not used as an
  external storage by your computer
  (the connection type should be
  `charhe only`),
- your SD card is not full.

Answer (score 0):

In the manifest file for the application you can set the android:installLocation value to 'preferExternal' - see the documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html#install).

There's no guarantee that the preference will be honored, but the SD card would be the default if you set preferExternal.

Answer (score 0):

IF you have included android:installLocation="preferExternal" then after installing application go to settings->application->manage application from there you can move application to SD card.

Else Try [this](http://androinica.com/2010/08/how-to-install-apps-to-the-sd-card-by-default-on-android-2-2-froyo/). It may help you.